Is there a way to flag which class-level Moq setups are never called?
We've been using xUnit and Moq for our (C#) unit tests for nearly 10 years. Over that time, as you can imagine, our code has changed an awful lot, and one of the results is that we now have a whole lot of "stale" Moq setup calls in our unit tests. Maybe 5 years ago, that setup was required, but enough has changed with the class under test so that particular Moq setup is no longer needed. In my testing, depending on the test class, maybe about a third of our setups are no longer needed. They're not really causing any direct problems, but they add a lot of clutter and cruft that I'd really like to get rid of.
Is there any way to find and flag all of those unused setups, so that we can go about removing them?
One obvious way is to comment them out one-by-one, run the tests after each one gets commented out, and see if anything breaks. However, we have hundreds of unit test classes, with thousands of setups, and the comment/build/run cycle takes maybe 3-5 minutes per mocked setup. That's really not scalable.
Another obvious way is to call .VerifyAll() on the mocked objects after the test is finished. The problem with that is that it requires setting up all the mocks at the test level, and almost never at the class level. This would add a whole crap-ton of boilerplate code to each test, and is maybe worse than what we have now. (We've taken the obvious shortcut of doing much of our mocking in the test class constructor, so that we don't need to do the setups directly from each test. This means that some of the class-level setups are only needed for some tests - but they are in fact needed for those tests.)
Any ideas? Anyone else run into this problem before and come up with a plausible solution?

You can use .Verify() on individual mock setups in each test method. This will allow you to verify that the mock was interacted with as expected during the test and can be used to flag unnecessary setups.

The problem with that approach is that it requires that you do the setups individually for each test, which results in a whole lot of boilerplate being repeated for each test.
